# Why am I getting a syntax error for my code on the last elif statement; I want it to be on the same block as the first if statement

Tags: python

```
# import random
# random_number = random.randint(1,1000)
random_number = int(input("Enter a number from 1000"))
guess = 500
high_value = 1000
low_value = 0
guess_counter = 0

if random_number > 500:
    for i in range(0,10):
        if guess == random_number:
            # print("You got it {}".format(guess))
            # print(("you got it {}".format(random_number)))
            print("The random number was {}".format(random_number))
            break
        if guess < random_number:
            low_value = guess
            guess = low_value + (high_value - low_value)//2
            high_value = 2*(guess - low_value) + low_value
            guess_counter += 1
            print("Guess # {}, your guess was {}".format(guess_counter, guess))
        else:
            high_value = guess
            guess = low_value + (high_value - low_value)//2
            low_value = -2*guess + 2*low_value + high_value
            guess_counter += 1
            print("Guess # {}, your guess was {}".format(guess_counter, guess))

guess = 250
random_number = int(random_number)
elif random_number < 500:
     print("hi")
```

Trying not to get a syntax error here. Why am I getting a syntax error for my code on the last elif statement; I want it to be on the same block as the first if statement.

Comment: Because you made assignments in between

Comment: Your `elif` is not connected to the `if`. What do the two lines before the `elif` mean?

Comment: these lines "guess = 250
random_number = int(random_number)" break your "if" so you either need to put them indented or move them

Answer (score 0):

Corrected it for you, the `if` and `elif` need to be indented the same:

```py
import random
# random_number = random.randint(1,1000)
random_number = int(input("Enter a number from 1000"))
guess = 500
high_value = 1000
low_value = 0
guess_counter = 0

if random_number > 500:
    for i in range(0,10):
        if guess == random_number:
            # print("You got it {}".format(guess))
            # print(("you got it {}".format(random_number)))
            print("The random number was {}".format(random_number))
            break
        if guess < random_number:
            low_value = guess
            guess = low_value + (high_value - low_value)//2
            high_value = 2*(guess - low_value) + low_value
            guess_counter += 1
            print("Guess # {}, your guess was {}".format(guess_counter, guess))
        else:
            high_value = guess
            guess = low_value + (high_value - low_value)//2
            low_value = -2*guess + 2*low_value + high_value
            guess_counter += 1
            print("Guess # {}, your guess was {}".format(guess_counter, guess))
    guess = 250
    random_number = int(random_number)
elif random_number < 500:
     print("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

because

```
guess = 250
random_number = int(random_number)
```

this lines is not continue if without indet so you can't use elif after

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a syntax error because guess = 250 and random_number = int(random_number) needs to be indent. This said based of the assumption that you are trying to write a number guessing game there are also many logic errors in your code.